# Как запретить перерендеринг компонента в react

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть большая таблица, по нажатию на строку нужно открывать модальное окно. State родительского компонента схематично выглядит так

```
state = {
    tableData: [],
    modaShow:  true/false
}
```

Когда я открываю модалку, я меняю состояние в родительском элементе modalShow: true, что заставляет таблицу перерисовываться тоже. Когда данных много, рендеринг заметно тормозит. Как можно запретить перерендеринг таблицы в момент открытия модального окна?

Comment: Похоже, что у вас свойство modalShow передаётся в компонент, который отрисовывает таблицу. Если убрать передачу этого свойства в компонент с таблицей, то и обновляться этот компонент не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если таблица находится в той же компоненте где и происходят изменения modalShow, то вынести ее в отдельную компоненту и передавать в props только tableData.

- Если таблица статичная (нужно отрисовать только 1 раз и никаких изменений не вносить), то можно добавить

  ```
  shouldComponentUpdate() {
      return false;
  }
  ```
- Если таблица динамически изменяется, то внутри shouldComponentUpdate() сравнивать tableData и в зависимости от результата перерисовывать или нет компоненту.

  ```
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
      // вместо !== будет какое то сравнение между this.props.tableData и nextProps.tableData
      return this.props.tableData !== nextProps.tableData
  }
  ```